Issue with Filtering Overlapping Dates and Times in TypeScript
Hello everyone,
I'm working on an Angular project where I need to filter a list of courses based on selected weeks and ensure that the courses do not overlap in date and time. However, my current filter does not seem to work properly and allows some courses to overlap.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
semana = [
  { label: 'Week 1 - June 24 to June 28', value: 1 },
  { label: 'Week 2 - July 1 to July 5', value: 2 },
  { label: 'Week 3 - July 8 to July 12', value: 3 }
];

this.carrera1Form = combineLatest([
  this.store$.pipe(select(selectCareersList)),
  this.inscribedForm.get('semana1').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.inscribedForm.get('semana1').value)),
  this.inscribedForm.get('carrera2').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.inscribedForm.get('carrera2').value))
]).pipe(
  map(([carreras, semana1, carrera2Selected]) => {
    if (!semana1) return [];
    let filteredCarreras = carreras.filter(carrera => carrera.semana === +semana1);
    if (carrera2Selected) {
      const selectedCarrera2 = carreras.find(c => c.id === carrera2Selected);
      if (selectedCarrera2) {
        filteredCarreras = filteredCarreras.filter(c => {
          return (c.fecha_inicio_hora_fin <= selectedCarrera2.fecha_inicio_hora_inicio || c.fecha_fin_hora_inicio >= selectedCarrera2.fecha_fin_hora_fin);
        });
      }
    }
    return filteredCarreras.map(carrera => ({ label: `${carrera.nombre}`, value: carrera.id }));
  }),
  tap(filteredCarreras => console.log('Filtered Careers for Carrera1:', filteredCarreras))
);

this.carrera2Form = combineLatest([
  this.store$.pipe(select(selectCareersList)),
  this.inscribedForm.get('semana2').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.inscribedForm.get('semana2').value)),
  this.inscribedForm.get('carrera').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.inscribedForm.get('carrera').value))
]).pipe(
  map(([carreras, semana2, carreraSelected]) => {
    if (!semana2) return [];
    let filteredCarreras = carreras.filter(carrera => carrera.semana === +semana2);
    if (carreraSelected) {
      const selectedCarrera = carreras.find(c => c.id === carreraSelected);
      if (selectedCarrera) {
        filteredCarreras = filteredCarreras.filter(c => {
          return (c.fecha_inicio_hora_fin <= selectedCarrera.fecha_inicio_hora_inicio || c.fecha_fin_hora_inicio >= selectedCarrera.fecha_fin_hora_fin);
        });
      }
    }
    return filteredCarreras.map(carrera => ({ label: `${carrera.nombre}`, value: carrera.id }));
  })
);

Here is the HTML part:
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
  <label for="inputtext">Week of the stay <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <p-dropdown id="inputtext" [options]="semana" formControlName="semana1"
    placeholder="Select an option" [appendTo]="'body'"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
  <label for="inputtext">Career 1<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <p-dropdown id="inputtext" [options]="carrera1Form | async" formControlName="carrera"
    placeholder="Select an option" [appendTo]="'body'"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
  <label for="inputtext">Status of the stay <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <p-dropdown id="inputtext" [options]="estatus_estancia" formControlName="estatus_estancia" [optionDisabled]="isOptionDisabled" [disabled]="inscribed.estatus_general == 4"
    placeholder="Select an option" [appendTo]="'body'"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
  <label for="inputtext">Week of the stay 2 </label>
  <p-dropdown id="inputtext" [options]="semana" formControlName="semana2"
    placeholder="Select an option" [appendTo]="'body'"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
  <label for="inputtext">Career 2 </label>
  <p-dropdown id="inputtext" [options]="carrera2Form | async" formControlName="carrera2"
    placeholder="Select an option" [appendTo]="'body'"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
  <label for="inputtext">Status of the stay 2<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <p-dropdown id="inputtext" [options]="estatus_estancia" [optionDisabled]="isOptionDisabled" formControlName="estatus_estancia2" [disabled]="inscribed.estatus_general == 4"
    placeholder="Select an option" [appendTo]="'body'" ></p-dropdown>
</div>

The data I am working with is as follows:
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Chemical Engineering", "week": 1, "capacity": 12, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719241200, "end_time_1": 1719248400, "start_time_2": 1719586800, "end_time_2": 1719594000},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Mechanical Engineering", "week": 1, "capacity": 25, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719248400, "end_time_1": 1719255600, "start_time_2": 1719594000, "end_time_2": 1719601200},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Industrial Engineering", "week": 1, "capacity": 25, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719241200, "end_time_1": 1719259200, "start_time_2": 1719586800, "end_time_2": 1719604800},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Mechatronics Engineering Group 1", "week": 1, "capacity": 24, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719241200, "end_time_1": 1719248400, "start_time_2": 1719586800, "end_time_2": 1719594000},
  {"id": 5, "name": "Mechatronics Engineering Group 2", "week": 1, "capacity": 24, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719252000, "end_time_1": 1719259200, "start_time_2": 1719597600, "end_time_2": 1719604800},
  {"id": 6, "name": "Fashion Design", "week": 1, "capacity": 30, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719241200, "end_time_1": 1719255600, "start_time_2": 1719500400, "end_time_2": 1719514800},
  {"id": 7, "name": "Financial Engineering", "week": 1, "capacity": 30, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719241200, "end_time_1": 1719255600, "start_time_2": 1719500400, "end_time_2": 1719514800},
  {"id": 8, "name": "Communication, Art and Culture Rally Morning Group", "week": 1, "capacity": 60, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719244800, "end_time_1": 1719259200, "start_time_2": 1719590400, "end_time_2": 1719604800},
  {"id": 9, "name": "Communication, Art and Culture Rally Afternoon Group", "week": 1, "capacity": 60, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719262800, "end_time_1": 1719277200, "start_time_2": 1719608400, "end_time_2": 1719622800},
  {"id": 10, "name": "Education Sciences", "week": 1, "capacity": 25, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719331200, "end_time_1": 1719342000, "start_time_2": 1719504000, "end_time_2": 1719514800},
  {"id": 11, "name": "Architecture", "week": 1, "capacity": 60, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719331200, "end_time_1": 1719342000, "start_time_2": 1719504000, "end_time_2": 1719514800},
  {"id": 12, "name": "Philosophy and Social Sciences", "week": 1, "capacity": 25, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719500400, "end_time_1": 1719509400, "start_time_2": 1719586800, "end_time_2": 1719595800},
  {"id": 13, "name": "Technological Rally", "week": 2, "capacity": 72, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719846000, "end_time_1": 1719864000, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720123200},
  {"id": 14, "name": "Nanotechnology Engineering", "week": 2, "capacity": 40, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719846000, "end_time_1": 1719853200, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720112400},
  {"id": 15, "name": "Nutrition", "week": 2, "capacity": 24, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719846000, "end_time_1": 1719860400, "start_time_2": 1720018800, "end_time_2": 1720033200},
  {"id": 16, "name": "Design Group 1", "week": 2, "capacity": 20, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719846000, "end_time_1": 1719864000, "start_time_2": 1720018800, "end_time_2": 1720036800},
  {"id": 17, "name": "Design Group 2", "week": 2, "capacity": 20, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1720018800, "end_time_1": 1720036800, "start_time_2": 1720191600, "end_time_2": 1720209600},
  {"id": 18, "name": "Sustainable Real Estate Development", "week": 2, "capacity": 25, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1720022400, "end_time_1": 1720033200, "start_time_2": 1720195200, "end_time_2": 1720206000},
  {"id": 19, "name": "Rally of Sociopolitical Studies", "week": 2, "capacity": 40, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719849600, "end_time_1": 1719860400, "start_time_2": 1720022400, "end_time_2": 1720033200},
  {"id": 20, "name": "Marketing and Commercial Management", "week": 2, "capacity": 50, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719932400, "end_time_1": 1719946800, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720119600},
  {"id": 21, "name": "Finance", "week": 2, "capacity": 30, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719932400, "end_time_1": 1719950400, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720123200},
  {"id": 22, "name": "Accounting and Corporate Governance", "week": 2, "capacity": 25, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719932400, "end_time_1": 1719950400, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720123200},
  {"id": 23, "name": "Business Administration and Entrepreneurship", "week": 2, "capacity": 50, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719932400, "end_time_1": 1719950400, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720123200},
  {"id": 24, "name": "Hospitality and Tourism", "week": 2, "capacity": 40, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719932400, "end_time_1": 1719946800, "start_time_2": 1720105200, "end_time_2": 1720119600},
  {"id": 25, "name": "Human Resources and Organizational Talent", "week": 2, "capacity": 20, "active": 1, "start_time_1": 1719932400, "end_time_1": 1719943200, "start_time_2": 1720105200}]

I want to ensure that when selecting two courses from the same week, they do not overlap in times. For example, the courses can be on the same day but should not be at the same time. Currently, my filter seems to allow some overlapping courses.
Can anyone help me identify what might be wrong with my filter logic or suggest a better way to handle this?
Thank you!
